# making objects, constructor with va_list

Tags: c++

I got problem with va_list. I used it in constructor to get unexpected amount of data to my object. The problematic code is there:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class DATA{
    private:
        int length;
        int* tab;
    public:
        DATA():tab(NULL), length(0){};
        DATA(int x, ...):length(x+1){
            va_list ap;
            va_start(ap, x);
            tab=new int[length];
            for(int i=0; i<length; ++i){
                tab[i]=va_arg(ap, int);
            }
            va_end(ap);
        }
        void showthem()const{
            if(tab!=NULL){
                int x;
                for(x=0; x<length-1; ++x){
                    cout<<tab[x]<<", ";
                }
                cout<<tab[x];
            }
        }
}
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const DATA & x){
    x.showthem();
    return out;
}
int main(){
    int table [] = {5,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    DATA x1(*table);
    DATA x2(4,1,2,3,4,5);
    cout << x1 << endl;
    cout << x2 << endl;
}
```

When I make object naturally by writing all parameters it's okay, but when i try to make it by a table it making problem.
I got unexpected data in class tab.

I guess I am making something wrong. In forst way - can I even make object like this via *table? I am giving to the constructor some amount of integers so it should work...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not make sense.

Comment: First of all, variadic functions are not to be used in C++. Second of all, self-made dynamic arrays are not to be used in C++. Third of all, if you are hell-bent on using variadic functions, you need to learn how to do this. Right now your code makes no sense.

Comment: `DATA x1(*table)` would be `DATA x1(5)`...

Comment: The table is being passed as a pointer, The constructor is only getting one argument of type int*

Comment: `std::vector` is better here.

Comment: std::initializer_list might be what he wants. But after seeing operator<< implementation, I would recommend to stick with std::vector

Answer (score 1):

KIIV nailed it. `std::initializer_list` ([documentation linked here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)) is exactly what OP needs.

Forget about variable arguments lists. They allow hard-to-debug programs several different ways. For example,

```
DATA x2(41,2,3,4,5)
```

Whoops! Missed a comma and gonna read waaaaaay out of range on the stack! Or

```
DATA x2(5, 1,2,3,4,"I am the very model of a modern major-general...")
```

Which would be a lot easier to spot, but still compiles because the compiler doesn't know or care what types the varadic function allows.

But an `initializer_list<int>` will only allow `int`s and you don't have to specify the number of `int`s. One less potential error right there!

Fixing up a few of the obvious mis-steps and ignoring the [elephant in the room, `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), for the time being we get something that looks like

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

class DATA{
    private:
        int length;
        int* tab;
    public:
        DATA(std::initializer_list<int> vals):
            length(vals.size()), tab(new int[length])
        {
            int index = 0;
            for(int val: vals){
                tab[index]=val;
                index++;
            }
        }
        DATA(const DATA& src) = delete;
        DATA& operator=(const DATA& src) = delete;

        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const DATA & x){
            if(x.tab!=NULL){
                int index=0;
                out<<x.tab[index];
                for(index++; index < x.length; ++index){
                    out<<", "<<x.tab[index];
                }
            }
            return out;
        }
};
int main(){
    DATA x1({1,2,3,4,5});
    std::cout << x1 << std::endl;
}
```

Note the `{}` braces in `DATA x1({1,2,3,4,5});` This establishes the list. The list knows how big it is, so you don't have to BLEEP around with telling the function how many items are coming.

Note that I have deleted the copy constructor and assignment operator. This is because of The Rule of Three. [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) Read the link and find out. It'll save you a lot of future debugging.

This is also ludicrously easy to template:

```
template <class TYPE>
class DATA{
    private:
        int length;
        TYPE* tab;
    public:
        DATA(std::initializer_list<TYPE> vals):
            length(vals.size()), tab(new TYPE[length])
        {
            int index = 0;
            for(const TYPE& val: vals){
                tab[index]=val;
                index++;
            }
        }

        DATA(const DATA& src) = delete;
        DATA& operator=(const DATA& src) = delete;

        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const DATA & x){
            if(x.tab!=NULL){
                int index=0;
                out<<x.tab[index];
                for(index++; index < x.length; ++index){
                    out<<", "<<x.tab[index];
                }
            }
            return out;
        }
};

int main(){
    DATA<int> x1({1,2,3,4,5});
    DATA<std::string> x2({"I", "am", "the", "very", "model", "of", "a", "modern", "major-general"});
    std::cout << x1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << x2 << std::endl;
}
```